# Prime factorization and divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given two positive integers $n$ and $m$, $ m \leqslant n$. Can we say that if $m \nmid n$ then there is a prime integer $p$ such that $n = p^{k}r$, $m = p^{l}s$, with $r$ and $s$ relatively prime to $p$ and $k < l$?

Could you help me come up with a proof/solid arguments so that I won't use these just as a fact?

Comment: Hint:  Write out the unique factorization of both $m,n$.  If your desired inequality fails at each prime, show that $m$ divides $n$.

Comment: Your second question is unclear as it refers to the conclusion of the first question which in turn contradicts the rest of the second question (you can't both have $k<l$ and $k\ge l$). Please reformulate so that the question doesn't refer to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second question is unclear, but the answer to the first is yes.

You can prime factor $n=\prod\pi_j^{n_j}$ and $m= \prod\pi_j^{m_j}$. For $m$ to divide $n$ you must have $m_j\le n_j$ universally. Reversely if $m\not\mid n$ you have one $j$ such that $m_j>n_j$, and the rest of the prime factorization is relatively prime to $\pi_j$.

Using your notation with $p=\pi_j$ and $k=n_j$ and $l=m_j$, $r=\prod_{i\ne j}\pi_i^{n_i}$ and $q=\prod_{i\ne j}\pi_i^{m_i}$.